# How to get drive SERIAL number from mountpoint?

Tags: command-line, scripting, mount, hard-disk

If `lsblk -o NAME,SERIAL,MOUNTPOINT` includes the following in its output

```
sdb                                           X55MM4827123
└─sdb1
  └─luks-4d0dc651-9aa6-452d-9442-7b33d95f8427                /run/media/main/mydrive
```

What is a simple console/CLI command I can use to get the serial number (`X55MM4827123` in this case) when I provide the mountpoint (`/run/media/main/mydrive` in this case)?

The answer doesn't necessarily have to use `lsblk`, but it should hopefully be concise and ideally use just simple bash scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, the goal is to give the command input as mountpoint and output serial number. Well, it's possible with a small script that uses a little bit of `awk` magic and `smartmontools` package.

Demo<sup>2</sup>:

```
$ ./mount2serial.sh /                                                                                                    
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
Serial Number:    4G7AA3Q1HSZ4HH4YN
$ ./mount2serial.sh /mnt/HDD                                                                                             
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
Serial Number:    4O75CEXFLML9M
```

And here's script itself:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$1" = "/"  ]
then
    dev=$(awk -v mount="$1" '$2 == mount{print $1}' /proc/self/mounts)
else
    dev=$(awk -v mount="$1" '$0 ~ mount{print $1}' /proc/self/mounts)
fi
sudo smartctl -i "$dev" | grep 'Serial Number:'
```

---

Since you do get serial number in `lsblk`, and GNU version<sup>1</sup> of `lsblk`  can output JSON data, I've put together a Python script that works as so<sup>2</sup>:

```
$ ./mount2serial.py '/mnt/ubuntu'
4O75CEXFLML9M
xie@xie-PC:~$ ./mount2serial.py '/'
B4VOM8OEIZIHF
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import subprocess
import sys

lsblk = subprocess.run(['lsblk','-J','-o','NAME,SERIAL,MOUNTPOINT'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for dev in json.loads(lsblk.stdout.decode())['blockdevices']:
    serial = ''
    # find serial number of current block device
    for key,value in dev.items():
        if key == 'serial':
            serial = value
            break
    # we don't need to iterate through everything in dev.items()
    for child in dev['children']:
        if child['mountpoint'] == sys.argv[1]:
            print(serial)
            sys.exit(0)
# if nothing is found we end up here with exit status 1 and nothing printed
sys.exit(1)
```

<sup>1. I've no idea if non-GNU versions of `lsblk` exist, but if they do - leave a comment</sup>

<sup>2. Serial numbers shown are random strings generated from `/dev/urandom` for demo purposes</sup>

Comment: Do you know how to make this work with a luks device? `smartctl` gives an error "Unable to detect device type".

Comment: @user779159 Unfortunately, no, but if I happen to figure it out someday I'll update my answer

Comment: @user779159 Actually, since you do get serial number from `lsblk`, I've added a Python script that parses output of that command. That's the best solution I can provide thus far

Answer (score 3):

These options will print your disk serial without headings: `lsblk -n -o SERIAL /dev/sda`

Options explained, and that can be found at the manpages:

```
-n, --noheadings
Do not print a header line.
```

This option will remove headers like `Serial:` from the command output.

```
-o, --output list
Specify which output columns to print. Use --help to get a list of all supported columns.
```

Select what information to print about disks.

This will be enough to bring you only the serial. Unfortunately, `lsblk` does not work with mountpoints, since the serial is an attribute of the disk, not the partition. Taking a look at the `synopsis`:

```
Synopsis

lsblk [options]
lsblk [options] device...
```

You will have to make a huge effort to extract from the mountpoint the partition, trim the disk information and then, supply it as parameter to `lsblk`. This will probably do the trick:

```
mount| grep /run/media/main/mydrive | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'|sed 's/[0-9]*//g'
```

`mount` will list all mountpoints, `grep` will get the line of your mountpoint, `awk` will get the partition column and `sed` will remove numbers, that are the representation of partitions. Summing all:

```
lsblk -n -o SERIAL `mount| grep /run/media/main/mydrive | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'|sed 's/[0-9]*//g'`
```

Comment: The `sed` is replacing the numbers, so the mount/grep/awk command results in `/dev/mapper/luks-ddc-aa-d--bdf`, even though luks should have a uuid after it.

Comment: Oh boy, Forgot that you have a disk encryption based on `luks`. I've tested with LVM and plain devices but not with those. Give me some time and i will fix this. But now, we have another problem that is: Nested devices. You have a Luks device, created on top of a disk device. This will be hard to fix, since we will have to probe all the possibilities(`mdraid`, `sda`, `lvm`, `luks`...)

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I'm not using lvm or mdraid, just luks.